# $\int_0^{2\pi} \text{arctan} \Big[\frac{\text{sin}\ \theta}{\text{cos}\ \theta +3}\Big] d\theta$

Tags: complex-analysis

I've been asked to solve this definite integral:

$$ \int_0^{2\pi} \text{arctan} \Big[\frac{\text{sin}\ \theta}{\text{cos}\ \theta +3}\Big] d\theta$$

It's obvious that it is finite and a bad approximation is $<\pi^2$. One can say more because it can be proven that the integrand is odd, so the result is $0$.

However I'm not interested in this solution because I need a way to see it using Complex Analysis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly, the integrand equals 
$$\Im \ln (\cos \theta+3+i\sin\theta)=\Im\ln(3+e^{i\theta})$$

By the substitution $z=e^{i\theta}$, the integral becomes
$$\Im\oint_{|z|=1}\ln(3+z)\frac{dz}{iz}=\Im \, 2\pi i\cdot\frac{\ln 3}{i}=0$$
by residue theorem.